# How to create an app that opens external URL then scroll the page down?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I want to create an app using **nodejs & Gulpjs** that opens a specific URL then scroll the page of the URL down to the end of the page, is that possible ?

Here is my code inside **gulpfile.js**

```
const {series, src, dest} = require('gulp');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var open  =require('open');
var https = require('https');

async function getLinks(params) {
    var pageLink = 'https://youtube.com';
    var links = [];

    open(pageLink, {app: 'chrome'});

    https.get(pageLink, (res) => {
        let rawHtml = '';
        res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawHtml += chunk; });
        res.on('end', () => {
            try {
                console.log(rawHtml);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e.message);
            }
        });
    });

}

exports.default = getLinks;
```

I would be **thankful** for some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that without the use of extensions or some external program exactly what you are looking for is currently possible, but there are some potential alternatives that may help you accomplish some of what you are aiming to do.

## ID's

If the page you are linking to has ID's for the element you want to link to you can append that to the end of URL. For example if you wanted to link to an element with the id of `#pricing` your link would look like this:

`https://example.com#pricing`

Obviously this is only useful on some pages, and only with elements that have ID's.

## Text Fragments

These are slightly closer to what you may be looking for in that it allows you to link to anywhere on a page, regardless of whether the element has an ID or not. Here is an example of how you would link to the `More information...` text on `example.com`:

`http://example.com/#:~:text=more%20information...`

Unfortunately this still has some cons, chiefly in the browser support arena. [According to caniuse only Chromium browsers currently supports the feature. (That is 71% of users though)](https://caniuse.com/url-scroll-to-text-fragment).

Comment: Thanks for all your effort but this is not going to attain my purpose.
How about append scripts to the url doc after opening it, is it possible ?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do that without it being part of some browser extension or other program.